# How to verify symbol value in r testthat?

Tags: r, unit-testing, testthat

What's the correct way of testing equality in a symbol?

I've tried

```
expect_equal( tsibble::index(bngoRawData), "time" )
```

but it fails with:

```
tsibble::index(bngoRawData) (`actual`) not equal to "time" (`expected`).

`actual` is a symbol
`expected` is a character vector ('time')
```

Without the quotes on "time" it complains it's a function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `as.name`:

```r
library(tsibble)
library(testthat)
expect_equal(tsibble::index(pedestrian), as.name("Date_Time"))
```

Alternatively we can use `rlang::sym`.